# Question about the heine-Borel property

Tags: real-analysis

We know that a compact subset $M$ of a metric space is closed and bounded. However, my teacher said the converse if false. To see this

Take metric space $ l^2 $ and consider the sequence $(e_n) = (0,0,.......,1,0,0,...........)$ with $1$ in the $nth$ place. We know $||e_n|| = 1$ so $(e_n$) is bounded. Im confused as which space is $M$ here ? Is it $M = (e_n)$ ?. And how is it true that it is closed and hence non compact ? Im having hard time seeing this .

Comment: The space is (usually) the closed (and bounded) unit ball in $l^2$. The collection (Sequence, actually) {$e_n$} is a sequence in $l^2$; it shows this unit ball is not compact.

Comment: have you grasped the definition of compact spaces in terms of open covers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the subset {$e_n$}:=$(0,0,...0,1,0,...,0,...)$ i.e., $e_n=0$ for the $n$-th spot, and it is $0$ otherwise. Then {$e_n$} is contained in the unit ball in $l^2$. I think it is straightforward to show {$e_n$} is closed, by showing the complement in $l^2$ is open, and it is clearly bounded. Now, remember that if a set $S$ is a compact metric space, then every sequence has a convergent subsequence. Remember too, that convergent sequences are Cauchy. Can you relate that to your sequence?